# T-SQL input parameter as stringArray()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing update query 
`"Update tbl_List Set ListName = 'Hello' where ListId IN (stringArray())`.

I have added 5 string values in **`stringArray()`** and how to pass it as input parameter to SQL ? How to execute query with `Array` values?

Comment: `ListId ` is string?

Comment: Yes, it's String

Comment: See [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your query as :

```
Update tbl_List Set ListName = 'Hello' where ListId IN ('value1' , 'value2' ,'valueN');
```

Or using a table :

```
Declare @Val Table (IDs Nvarchar(50) );

Insert into @val values ('value1'),('value2'),('valueN');

Update tbl_List Set ListName = 'Hello' where ListId IN (Select IDs From @Val);
```

You can loop in your `StringArray` to pass values , and you can use only one parametre and excute your query as much as the length of your `Array`.

Also you can use `temp tables` for that job.